# Scroll in the HTML file without scrolling bars

Tags: windows, browser, html, javascript

I have a HTML file with javascript, which adds to the mouse wheel zoom function (instead of scroll).

Scroll bars aren't displayed and moving up-down-right-left is only through drag-and-drop with the mouse possible.

`PageUp` and `PageDown` don't work too.

Trying to screenshot makes screenshot of area only visible in the browser window - not from the whole page content.

My **q**uestion is: how is it possible,

- at least, to scroll down with `PageDown` (to make consecutive screenshots),
- or, in the best case, to save the whole page (not only the area visible in browser) as image/pdf.

Comment: Sounds like you’re looking at a map. You’re already looking at the whole page. Except for a very small area outside the visible page, the rest is probably only loaded on-demand. That’s because this is a web application.

Comment: Unfortunately an easier way to solve this problem is off topic at Super User. There are screenshot applications that can capture an entire webpage with one mouse click, not just the part of the webpage that is currently visible in the web browser. For more information about which screenshot application I'm referring to visit [Software Recommendations Q&A](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @karel there are no such tools, which can scroll page, having no scroll. Ergo: no screenshot tool can make "whole page" screenshot - they all will screenshot just a visible page area.

Comment: Firefox has Firefox Screenshots tool built-in and it works like a charm: https://screenshots.firefox.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but from what I know there is no easy way to do this. Unless you are skilled enough to use Developer Tools (F12) in your browser.

For example in Google Chrome:

1. right click on the area you want to make a picture of
2. select "Inspect"
3. in Styles pane on the right side you may try adding following CSS styles, which should give you ability to hopefully scroll the page:

   - overflow
   - width
   - height

[see this DevTools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIbtj.png)

For example:

```
element.style {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

You might need to play a bit with the values, and/or other CSS styles if necessary.
Since you did not provide the exact URL for the page in question, I am giving here just a generic answer.